# Laravel artisan route:list shows non-object Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. Recently I cloned sample project from github. When I try to execute `php artisan route:list` shows

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMemberType() on a non-object in /...app/Http/Controllers/Admin/BaseAdminController.php on line 91

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]    
Call to a member function getMemberType() on a non-object
```

BaseAdminController.php

```
public function __construct(EmployeeDetails $employeeDetails)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        if(Auth::user()->getMemberType() != 'employee') //Line 91
        {
            Auth::logout();
            return Redirect::to('secure/login');
        }
```

Comment: Which sample project did you clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fire artisan task, user object is not set, so `\Auth::user()` returns `null` and you see this error.

That's why you have to check if your app is running in console. You can do it via `\App::runningInConsole()` method.